# Проблемы с добавлением Google-аккаунта

Tags: android, firebase

Создаю приложение с использованием сервиса Firebase, с функцией авторизации с помощью Google-аккаунта. Имеется вот такой код LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ChooseGroupFragment.InterfaceCommunicator,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener {
private Button go_button, choose_group;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
private SignInButton mSignInButton;
private FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
private boolean CHECK = false;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES = "user_settings";
public static final String APP_PREFERENCES_GROUP = "Group";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
    mSharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    go_button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.go);
    mSignInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.add_account_button);
    choose_group = (Button)findViewById(R.id.group_button);
    go_button.setOnClickListener(this);
    mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    choose_group.setOnClickListener(this);
    mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com") // идентификатор ключа OAuth 2.0 для Web Client
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.go:
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPreferences.edit();
            if(!choose_group.getText().equals("Выбрать группу") && CHECK){
                editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_GROUP, choose_group.getText().toString());
                editor.apply();
                Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Добавьте Google-аккаунт и выберите вашу группу.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.group_button:
            if (CHECK){
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ChooseGroupFragment fragment = new ChooseGroupFragment();
                fragment.show(manager, "dialog");
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "Сначала добавьте свой Google-аккаунт", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        break;
        case R.id.add_account_button:
            Authorize();
        break;
    }
}
private void Authorize(){
    Intent athorizeIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(athorizeIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
@Override
public void TextDialog(String text) {
    choose_group.setText(text);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }else{
            // выполняется этот код, появляется сообщение ниже
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Google-SignIn failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct){
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mFirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    /*If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    signed in user can be handled in the listener.*/
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()){
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Аккаунт добавлен.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CHECK = true;
                }
            });
}
}
```

Запускаю приложение в режиме отладки. При нажатии на кнопку добавления аккаунта, появляется маленькое окно выбора, при выборе аккаунта окно закрывается, происходит ошибка в методе onActivityResult(), result.isSuccess() возвращает FALSE (указано комментарием в в моём коде). В логе ничего связанного с этим я найти не могу. google-services.json я добавил, отпечаток релизного ключа SHA-1 на месте. Не могу понять, то я мог упустить...

Comment: Вы, небось, запускаете не release версию приложения? Т.е. не подписываете оную релизным ключом? Скорее всего вам надо лишь добавить SHA-1 дебажного ключа в консоли и обновить google-services.json в проекте

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, вы правы. Теперь всё заработало. Постоянно спотыкаюсь об эти дебаг/релиз-ключи :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное вы  запускаете не release версию приложения. Т.е. не подписываете оную релизным ключом. Скорее всего вам надо лишь добавить SHA-1 дебажного ключа в консоли и обновить google-services.json в проекте